# Can I use Docker Compose profiles to add extra environment variables, expose more ports, and extra Dockerfile RUN commands on a per-environment basis?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a fairly standard Docker setup which runs php, mysql, etc.

These services are defined in a `docker-compose.yml` which looks something like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      API_KEY=[LIVE_API_KEY]
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html

# etc...
```

I would like to add some extra things *in my development environment only*, for example:

1. Adding extra PHP extensions (xdebug)
2. Exposing extra ports
3. Extra environment variables

Is there a way I can add extra configuration **on top of** the existing services inside the same `docker-compose.yml` file, and also add extra `RUN` commands to my Dockerfile to install more things, but **for my dev environment only**, without creating totally separate `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` files?

For example I would like to do:

```
# docker-compose.yml
# Change or add some variables for dev only
environment:
  API_KEY=[DEV_API_KEY]
  XDEBUG_MODE=debug
```

```
# docker-compose.yml
# Expose some ports for dev only
ports:
  9003:9003
```

```
# Dockerfile
# Add some commands to Dockerfile for dev only
RUN pecl install xdebug
```

I'm confused about whether I should be using: *Docker compose profiles* to do this, or *multi-stage builds*, a combination of these, or another approach entirely.

Comment: Maybe using a docker-compose.override.yml would be an approach. That said, yes, you can define a service with the same name in two flavours and you're completely free. Also, there is an "extends" feature (if I remember that name correctly), which allows you to do something like deriving from a base class in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files).  What you're describing is a pretty typical use for them, where the main `docker-compose.yml` file contains a base set of settings and a `docker-compose.override.yml` contains settings that developers might need.

For example, a base `docker-compose.yml` would contain settings you need in production, giving names for all of the images and assigning ports only as required:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app: # an Nginx reverse proxy with static assets built in
    image: registry.example.com/phpproxy:${APP_TAG:-latest}
    ports:
      - "${APP_PORT:-80}:80"
  php:
    image: registry.example.com/phpapp:${PHP_TAG:-latest}
    environment:
      PGHOST: database
  database:
    image: postgres:15
    volumes:
      pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

A `docker-compose.override.yml` file would explain how to build images and open more ports:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
  php:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9003:9003"
  database:
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

If the second file is named exactly `docker-compose.override.yml` then Compose will find it automatically; if you give it another name then you need to provide all of the Compose file names with `docker-compose -f` options, on every `docker-compose` invocation.

This mechanism doesn't allow you to build different images in different environments.  (This isn't usually a best Docker practice.)  I've seen some approaches to this using a multi-stage Dockerfile and the Compose `build: { target: }` setting to build the image only up to a specific stage.  The default target is the final build stage.

```bash
FROM php AS base
...

FROM base AS development
RUN pecl install xdebug

FROM base AS final
```

```yaml
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
```

Compose [profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) can only be used to enable and disable services, but not change their configuration.

Comment: Thanks; this is pretty much exactly what I did. My only concern about this approach is if somebody forgot to include `target: base` in the production environment. In that case, I assume the development stuff would get built as well which wouldn't be desirable.

Comment: The last stage in my sample Dockerfile is the `final` stage, so if you don't have a `target:` that last stage should be the default.  `final` is the same as `base` in this setup so you should get `base` if you omit `target:`.